# Excel API extract row and column from result

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I use the Microsoft JS API with Excel.
When I use the following code, I can `console.log` the result :

```
    lastCell.load('address');
```

Result : Sheet1!J2804

How can I offset from this cell in order to select A2804?
How can I get the value of the row and the value of the column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get these information from `range.address` such as "Sheet1!A1024".

if you want to get the index of row and column, you could use `range.columnIndex` and `range.rowIndex`

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    range.format.fill.color = "yellow";
    range.load();

    await context.sync();
    console.log("Row Index =" + range.rowIndex);
    console.log("Col Index =" + range.columnIndex);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I think you want `getOffsetRange(rowOffset, columnOffset)` as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview

you could do something like (assuming you wanted to offset back to the first or A column, but using the same row(s))

```js
const rng = lastCell.load('address');
const firstCol = rng.getOffsetRange(0, 1 - rng.columnIndex);
```